# reference a file in a java package with javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I want to use the following js function to insert an image on a webpage, but I am not referencing the icon file correctly.

```
function insertWarningIcon(value){
       return "<img src='/icons/Warning-icon.png' width='25%' height='25%' />";
}
```

The image is contained in a java package 'icons.'  The file's path is:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects\distributedTaskMonitor\src\java\icons\Warning-icon.png
```

The html file's path is:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects\distributedTaskMonitor\web\gridMain.html
```

Comment: What's the full path of your output document? `http://localhost/gridMain.html`, or `C:\....\gridMain.html`?

Comment: If you want to serve classpath resources, you need to stream them yourself, otherwise put them in the web content directory.

Comment: @RobW http://localhost:8080/distributedTaskMonitor/gridMain.html

Comment: @TedPrz Do you mean `http://localhost:8080/distributedTaskMonitor/web/gridMain.html`? (with `web`)? If yes, the correct path is: `distributedTaskMonitor/src/java/icons/Warning-icon.png` *or* `../src/icons/Warning-icon.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't point to src package from web pages, you have to put them into "WebContents" folder (it's outside of src folder)

eg.

```
WebContents/images/icons/icon1.png
```

is

```
<img src="images/icons/icon1.png"/>
```